# Escape UNIX character

Tags: shell, unix, replace, sed, escaping

This should be easy but i just can't get out of it:

I need to replace a piece of text in a .php file using the unix command-line.

using: `sudo sed -i '' 's/STRING/REPLACEMENT/g' /file.php` (The quotes after -i are needed because it runs on Mac Os X)

The string: `['password'] = "";` needs to be replaced by: `['password'] = "$PASS";`
$PASS is a variable, so it gets filled in.

I got up to something like:

`sudo sed -i '' 's/[\'password\'] = ""\;/[\'password\'] = "$PASS"\;/g' /file.php`

But as i'm new with UNIX i don't know what to escape...

What should be changed? Thanks!

Comment: the accepted answer doesn't actually work with arbitrary strings -- in fact, a malicious password could end the running sed command (the replace operation) and start another arbitrary one, doing any edits of that user's choice to your config file! Please consider the awk answer, or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to expand variable in sed, you have to use double quote, so something like

```
sed -i... "s/.../.../g" file
```

that is, you don't have to escape those single quotes, also you could use group reference to save some typing. you could try:

```
sudo sed -i '' "s/\(\['password'\] = \"\)\(\";\)/\1$PASS\2/g" /file.php
```

Comment: Just be aware that while it work fine if PASS only contains letters and digits it will fail cryptically for various other values of the variable PASS. For example try it with `PASS='foo/bar'`.

Comment: @EdMorton Failing cryptically is if you're lucky; it could also do arbitrary injection into the sed command if the user providing the password were malicious.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately sed cannot robustly handle variables that might contain various characters that are "special" to sed and shell. You need to use awk for this, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub():

```
gawk -v pass="$PASS" '{$0=gensub(/(\[\047password\047] = \")/,"\\1"pass,"g")}1' file
```

See how sed fails below when PASS contains a forward slash but awk doesn't care:

```
$ cat file
The string: ['password'] = ""; needs to be replaced

$ PASS='foo'
$ awk -v pass="$PASS" '{$0=gensub(/(\[\047password\047] = \")/,"\\1"pass,"g")}1' file
The string: ['password'] = "foo"; needs to be replaced
$ sed "s/\(\['password'\] = \"\)\(\";\)/\1$PASS\2/g" file
The string: ['password'] = "foo"; needs to be replaced

$ PASS='foo/bar'
$ awk -v pass="$PASS" '{$0=gensub(/(\[\047password\047] = \")/,"\\1"pass,"g")}1' file
The string: ['password'] = "foo/bar"; needs to be replaced
$ sed "s/\(\['password'\] = \"\)\(\";\)/\1$PASS\2/g" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
```

You need to use `\047` or some other method (e.g. `'"'"'` if you prefer) to represent a single quote within an awk script that's single-quote-delimitted.

In awks without gensub() you just use gsub() instead:

```
awk -v pass="$PASS" '{pre="\\[\047password\047] = \""; gsub(pre,pre pass)}1' file
```